# Oracle PL/SQL variable use causes error in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I execute the following statement:

```
DESC &TBL_NAME;
```

SQL developer prompts 2 times to ask the value of TBL_NAME. After I input the value twice , it reports:

```
DESC &TBL_NAME;
ERROR:                                                                                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ERROR: object  does not exist                                                                                                    

1 rows selected
```

If I use the variable sign "&" in other statements, it's all fine. It just doesn't work with the "Desc" statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same reuslt by below code but make sure you enter your table name in Capital letters

```
select trim(COLUMN_NAME),trim(DATA_TYPE) from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '&tn' order by column_id
```

Comment: It's not that I need it to work. I just want to know why.

Answer (score 0):

**&** is used to denote a substitution variable which accepts user inputs and returns a string , DESCRIBE syntax accepts table/view name which should not be enclosed in qoutation marks as string does.

DESCRIBE { table-Name | view-Name }

DESC &TBL_NAME == DESC "<'TBL_NAME'>"

```
desc "Employee";
```

**Output**

```
desc "Employee"
ERROR:                                
------------------------------------- 
ERROR: object Employee does not exist 

Desc Employee;
```

**Output**

```
desc Employee
Name       Null     Type          
---------- -------- ------------- 
CO_CD NOT NULL NUMBER(2) 
PAYEE_CODE NOT NULL VARCHAR2(7) 
PAYEE_NAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
TIN1             NUMBER(3) 
TIN2             NUMBER(3) 
TIN3             NUMBER(3) 
TIN4             NUMBER(5) 
FIRST_NAME          VARCHAR2(30) 
MID_NAME          VARCHAR2(30) 
LAST_NAME          VARCHAR2(30) 
ACTIVE_TAG          VARCHAR2(1) 
USER_ID          VARCHAR2(12) 
UPDT_DT          DATE      
CREATE_DT          DATE      
UPDT_BY          VARCHAR2(15) 
EMAIL_ADDR          VARCHAR2(100)
```

> **Note:** **&** is an exclusive
>   feature of SQL*Plus and should not be used in SQL Developer.
>
> For your reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB